# (Integración Continua) Error al generar pipeline, marca error en una clase que proviene de un ensamblado externo al proyecto

Tags: xamarin.ios, yml, vsts, pipeline, integración-continua

Estoy configurando mi pipeline en un archivo yml, ya funcionaba bien en una versión de mi app antigua, pero agregué una dll, para una funcionalidad nueva que necesito en mi app, pero ahora cuando corro de nuevo el pipeline, llega a el task de hacer el build y me marca error, que no encuentra las referencias a ese ensamblado que agregué, 
¿Hay algun 'task' que pueda resolver eso, o hay manera de hacer que funcione el build? 
No encuentro solución.

```
# Xamarin.iOS
# Build a Xamarin.iOS project.
# Add steps that install certificates, test, sign, and distribute an app, save build artifacts, and more:
# https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/xamarin

trigger:
- development

pool:
  vmImage: 'macos-latest'

variables:
  - name: configuration
    value: 'Release'

steps:
# To manually select a Xamarin SDK version on the Microsoft-hosted macOS agent,
# configure this task with the *Mono* version that is associated with the
# Xamarin SDK version that you need, and set the "enabled" property to true.
# See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=871629

- script: sudo $AGENT_HOMEDIRECTORY/scripts/select-xamarin-sdk.sh 5_12_0
  displayName: 'Select the Xamarin SDK version'
  enabled: false

- task: InstallAppleCertificate@2
  displayName: 'Install an Apple certificate'
  inputs:
    certSecureFile: '$(namecertificate)'
    certPwd: '$(P12password)'
    keychain: 'temp'

- task: InstallAppleProvisioningProfile@1
  displayName: 'Install an Apple provisioning profile'
  inputs:
    provProfileSecureFile: '$(provisionprofile)'


- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '**/*.sln'

- task: XamariniOS@2
  inputs:
    solutionFile: '**/*iOS.csproj'
    configuration: '$(configuration)'
    signingIdentity: $(APPLE_CERTIFICATE_SIGNING_IDENTITY)
    signingProvisioningProfileID: $(APPLE_PROV_PROFILE_UUID)
    packageApp: true

- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    contents: '**/*.ipa'
    targetFolder: '$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)'

- task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
  inputs:
    targetPath: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)'
    publishLocation: 'pipeline'
```

Éste es el error que me arroja el pipeline en el 'task' donde hace el build

```
  Custom/UI/DigimarcScannerViewRenderer.cs(7,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'DMSDK' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/Users/runner/runners/2.168.2/work/1/s/HEB.SAG.App/HEB.SAG.App.iOS/HEB.SAG.App.iOS.csproj]
  Custom/UI/DigimarcScannerViewRenderer.cs(26,34): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'DMSDetectorViewControllerDelegate' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/Users/runner/runners/2.168.2/work/1/s/HEB.SAG.App/HEB.SAG.App.iOS/HEB.SAG.App.iOS.csproj]
  Custom/UI/DigimarcScannerViewRenderer.cs(44,53): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'DMSDetectorViewController' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/Users/runner/runners/2.168.2/work/1/s/HEB.SAG.App/HEB.SAG.App.iOS/HEB.SAG.App.iOS.csproj]
  Custom/UI/DigimarcScannerViewRenderer.cs(44,95): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'DMSResolvedContent' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/Users/runner/runners/2.168.2/work/1/s/HEB.SAG.App/HEB.SAG.App.iOS/HEB.SAG.App.iOS.csproj]
  Custom/UI/DigimarcScannerViewRenderer.cs(44,131): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'DMSPayload' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/Users/runner/runners/2.168.2/work/1/s/HEB.SAG.App/HEB.SAG.App.iOS/HEB.SAG.App.iOS.csproj]
  Custom/UI/DigimarcScannerViewRenderer.cs(59,61): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'DMSDetectorViewController' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/Users/runner/runners/2.168.2/work/1/s/HEB.SAG.App/HEB.SAG.App.iOS/HEB.SAG.App.iOS.csproj]
  Custom/UI/DigimarcScannerViewRenderer.cs(59,103): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'DMSReaderResult' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/Users/runner/runners/2.168.2/work/1/s/HEB.SAG.App/HEB.SAG.App.iOS/HEB.SAG.App.iOS.csproj]
  Custom/UI/DigimarcScannerViewRenderer.cs(59,25): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'DMSPayload' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/Users/runner/runners/2.168.2/work/1/s/HEB.SAG.App/HEB.SAG.App.iOS/HEB.SAG.App.iOS.csproj]
  Custom/UI/DigimarcScannerViewRenderer.cs(64,46): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'DMSResolvedContentItem' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/Users/runner/runners/2.168.2/work/1/s/HEB.SAG.App/HEB.SAG.App.iOS/HEB.SAG.App.iOS.csproj]
  Custom/UI/DigimarcScannerViewRenderer.cs(28,16): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'DMSResolvedContentItem' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/Users/runner/runners/2.168.2/work/1/s/HEB.SAG.App/HEB.SAG.App.iOS/HEB.SAG.App.iOS.csproj]
  Custom/UI/DigimarcScannerViewRenderer.cs(223,35): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'DMSResolvedContentItem' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/Users/runner/runners/2.168.2/work/1/s/HEB.SAG.App/HEB.SAG.App.iOS/HEB.SAG.App.iOS.csproj]
  Custom/UI/DigimarcScannerViewRenderer.cs(82,16): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'DMSDetectorViewController' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/Users/runner/runners/2.168.2/work/1/s/HEB.SAG.App/HEB.SAG.App.iOS/HEB.SAG.App.iOS.csproj]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontré solución, el gitignore estaba excluyendo la dll de ese ensamblado en mi proyecto, entonces solo fue permitirle que añadiera esas dll a mi proyecto